# Colorize assembly output

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to print a string with white foreground and blue background:

```
[BITS 16]                               ;16 bit code
[ORG 0x7C00]                            ;Origin location

SECTION .DATA                           ;Data section
    output: db 'Hello World', 10, 0     ;Output string (10 = \n, 0 = \0)

;Entry point
main:                                   
    mov ax, 0x0000                      ;Initialize the ds register
    mov ds, ax                          ;ds isn't a general purpose register => value has to be copied

    mov si, output                      ;Load the string into the si register
    call printString                    ;Call the printString function

    jmp $                               ;Endless loop

;Prints output
printString:    
    mov ah, 0x0E                        ;Function 0x0E = Display character
    mov bh, 0x00                        ;Set the page number to zero
    mov bl, 0x1F                        ;Set the text attribute (0x1F = Blue bg, White fg)
    jmp printChar                       ;Jmp to printChar (just for code eroticism)

;Prints every char from output until 0
printChar:                              ;Jmp point to loop through the string
    lodsb                               ;Load the byte at si into al
    or al, al                           ;Sets the zero flag if al = 0
    jz return                           ;Return if the end of the string is reached

    int 0x10                            ;Call the bios video service
    jmp printChar                       ;Continue to print the string

;Returns to main
return:                                 ;Jmp point to return
    ret                                 ;Return to main

times 510-($-$$) db 0                   ;Fill the rest of the floppy with zeros
dw 0xAA55                               ;Boot loader signature
```

It prints "Hello World" and jumps to the next line but it's always grey on black. Shouldn't `mov bl, 0x1F` with `int 0x10` colorize it?

**EDIT**

If someone has the same problem: I added this function to change the color and removed the text attribute line:

```
setColors:
    mov ah, 0x06    ;Function 0x06 = Scroll up function
    xor cx, cx      ;From upper left corner
    mov dx, 0x184F  ;To lower right corner
    mov bh, 0x1F    ;Set colors (white on blue)
    int 10H         ;Call the bios video interrupt
    ret             ;Return
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't simply create your own output routines (full console API, if you are writing OS, or just simple "print" helpers for bootloader) by writing to `B800:0000` ignoring the slow BIOS completely?

Comment: Simply because i'm currently learning assembly and I wanted to go from the bottom up.

Comment: I see, that's fine, from the question it looks like you are doing good (although for the very basics I would rather use DOS emulation and create COM files first, which are quite similar to bootloader code in many ways, but DOS is more forgiving environment, especially in comparison with real HW BIOS, which tend to boot up with all kind of various quirks and unprepared bootloaders fail). So if you did master the `int 0x10` by now, you may take a peek on the direct [`B800:0000` memory access](http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/B800_Text), + add later VGA control regs, should be/have fun :)

Comment: (I'm not sure what you mean by "bottom up", I don't think like there's particular direction sense in assembly, it's quite flat in the end, once you understand everything in computer is encoded in 0 or 1 information called "bit", you know almost everything... Then add few ten thousand of pages of particular platform details, like modern x86 or GPU, and you know it all :) ... but rather try to glide on general levels, don't dig too deep into particular chipset/etc, most of that knowledge gets obsolete in a wink, while general principles tend to last decades, so keep looking for principles :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x0E` function of the `int 10h` BIOS routine, when printing characters, applies the foreground color defined in `BL` **only in the graphics mode**.

[Graphics Mode](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm)

[Int 10h - 0x0E](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm)